# How to change all 100 % height images in HTML to 50% height using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML files (i cant know what will be in then) by using javascript i need to resize all images that are 100 % height so they will be 50 % height.

Comment: Are you using jQuery, the solution is trivial if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do if you are only using javascript is get all the elements by tagname

```
var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i in imgs){
  if(imgs[i].height=="100%"){
       img[i].height="50%";
  }
}
```

Stack overflow is really not a good place for people to do your work for you.

Comment: sorry for stupid question i am only learning javascript i wont ask question animore if they will be easy as this one

Comment: well it did not help but i do not want to listen people blaming me.